# Possible paths on a rectangular grid moving also diagonally

Tags: combinatorics

The objective is to calculate the number of ways in which you can reach the bottom right corner of a N x M rectangular grid from the top left corner.
The hard part is that the problem says that you can move down, right, or diagonally downwards directions.
I am used to normal problems in which you can only move down or right, so I don't really know how to solve this! Any help?

Comment: These are the [*Delannoy numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delannoy_number).

Comment: Use the reccurence  relation :$U_{i,j}=U_{i-1,j}+U_{i,j-1}+U_{i-1,j-1}$

Comment: Aren't Delannoy numbers supposed to be used when moving diagonally only in one direction (down-right) in this case? Because the problem asks for BOTH diagonal directions, either down-right or down-left.